# Why do YUI’s Y.Lang.isNull() and Y.Lang.isUndefined() exist?

Tags: yui, javascript, javascript-framework

From time to time I come across JavaScript library/framework features, where I ask myself: why do we need this if there is a simple cross-browser solution already?

`Y.Lang.isNull(bla)` and `bla === null` look equal to me, while the latter is even more beautiful (same applies for “undefined”).

I don’t like it if there are several ways to do the same, without a single comment in the documentation on top.

I’m porting a pure JavaScript file to YUI, and later maybe to another framework and I’m asking myself: should I touch that line every time to look more framework-ish or just leave it alone? Is there any benefit?

Comment: "I don't like it if there are several ways to do the same, without a single comment in the documentation on top." Do not learn Perl...

Comment: I believe there is no added benefit; the YUI API methods are just pretty (or not) wrappers - https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/master/src/yui/js/yui-lang.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For null or undefined, you should go ahead and use a standard JS check for this.
A slightly longer explanation is here: [Y.Lang.isUndefined vs typeof undefined, which is better and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751609/y-lang-isundefined-vs-typeof-undefined-which-is-better-and-why)

Answer (score 1):

At YUI Conf 2012, Ryan Grove gave a presentation When Not to Use YUI.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8cTz73zdDuc

At 8:54 he says "Don't use YUI when vanilla JavaScript will do."
At 9:49 he specifically talks about not using most Y.Lang methods.
At 11:04 he says do not use Y.Lang.isNull.

Somewhere in there he explained that the reason for these methods' existence was for an edge case we would never see, and that the Y.Lang versions are slower than vanilla JavaScript.

At 11:40 he shows a chart on just how much slower. isNull is 48% slower in IE9.